# Whats the formal expression for picking up an exam ticket?

Tags: british-english

"May i take a ticket please ? " Or "May you allow me to pick up a ticket? " or whats the best suitable expression for this matter ?

Comment: Are you Russian? Because usually Russians call it a ticket. In English it's called "question sheet" or "exam paper". https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exam+paper

Comment: Also, I think it's mostly inherent to Russia to make students draw question sheets out of a pile.